# How to find length of object array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to get length of that array while using $project

```
{ $project: { 'chatCount' : {$size:"messages.chats"} }
```

where messages is the array returned via $lookup.

This gives only length as '1'

messages contains -> messages.chats[0],[1],[2]..as inner arrays

How can i get length of chats, (say 3 for above) via $size or any other

response appreciated..

Comment: Use "messages.chats.length" on the place of messages.chats.

Comment: can you post the output of your aggregation query without the $project stage ?

Comment: Add $unwind stage. `{$unwind: "$message.chats"}` before project stage

Comment: thanks, but messages.chats.length wont work

Comment: {$unwind: "$message"} gives the length, but it wont give the other data if message is empty while lookup performs, unwind gives the answer but only those values having messages after look is present else it is not showing other values too.. any update??

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with $unwind. unwind will not cause any data to disappear. The problem may be somwhere else. Consider updating the post with your results.

Comment: You should just need to add the `$` prefix to the field name: `$size: "$messages.chats"`

Comment: if i give `{ $project: { 'chatCount' : {$size:"$messages.chats"} }`   
it gives 0 for  the result **'chatCount : []'** and 1 for chatCount : [{"_id":"xxx", "comment":"hai"}, {"_id":"xxx", "comment":"helo"}]
but i need 2 as result there

Answer (score 0):

in first unwind the chats then project chats and _id and then use group like this

```
{
   $group : { _id: {"id":"$_id"} ,
             Count :{$sum: 1}
}
```

with this code you have each Id and chats count.